# Blender for android goes to gallery instead

Tags: game-engine

I'm using Blender on my Android tablet. It's a Lenovo A3300-HV. Every time I tap on "Select Game", instead of going to my file browser or ZArchiver, it goes to my gallery instead.

Can someone help please? I'm really wanting to edit intros and I can't do it on my laptop cause it's broken.

Comment: Blender for Android was pretty much a one time experimental thing, as fa as I know. Not really supported or maintained at the level of desktop Blender and and certainly not for production work ready. If you want to use Blender I advise you fix your laptop or find a Windows, Linux, or Mac machine to use it on.