# Blender on Android

Tags: osx

Hello Community Members.
I want to install Blender on a Android OS computer , can this be done and what are the minimum system requirements.
If not can I access Blender on it’s cloud with an Android device.
All help is valued so much and appreciated with my current enquiry.
Best Always
Paul

Comment: Blender doesn't run on mobile platforms, only on Windows Mac and Linux, a little research would have taught you that. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51298/blender-for-android-goes-to-gallery-instead

Answer (score 0):

There was a hacky version, but the interface would be tough to navigate without mouse & keyboard.  https://www.blendernation.com/2015/02/12/using-blender-for-android/

Another method would be to open Blender on a PC with a VNC server running in the background, then remote access it through your Android device using a VNC viewer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing  Might be a bit laggy though, 'cuz everything you do will be running through a router.

Comment: Yes ! Ok Thanks for that might get a Windows OS instead seems easier and better , without complications , just straight forward , Best All